# Type inference in TS is too basic, or isn't it?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code:

```
var a; // it is typed "any". 
a = 33; // No inference
a = true; // compiles without errors.
```

It won't infer the type by first usage.

In Haxe:

```
var a; // it is now an "Unknown" kinda type, "monomorph"
a = 33; // Here it became int
a = true; // compiler error, unable to set int to bool.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is it possible to do it in TypeScript?

As far as I see, it's not possible. So this question could be a great warning for all OCaml or Haxe developers: you should initialize your variable *immediately* in TS.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript so valid JS code must also be valid TS code.

Comment: @JJJ No, TS's _syntax_ is a superset of JS _syntax_, but that doesn't mean that all JS code will compile in TS. The following is perfectly valid JavaScript but will fail to compile in TS: `var a = 33; a = true;`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the expectation was actually fairly valid from a functional view point to anyone used to inference.  I am sure that JLRishe will agree that languages like F# have proper inference, or atleast as far as I am aware they go a lot further than Typescript, but I am sure there will be differences with other hardcore functional languages.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd233180(v=vs.102)
'The idea of type inference is that you do not have to specify the types of F# constructs except when the compiler cannot conclusively deduce the type.'

Haxe has a very smart compiler and like F#, Ocaml etc... has very strong functional leaning in respect of full infered typing.  I think from a functional language perspective Typescript can only be considered a play script unless details like this are improved apon, a huge improvement over Javascript but really it's not in the same league as Haxe or F# in regard to inferance and typing. That said reality is that more people use Typescript so for instance it's pretty hardwork to use Haxe within say an Angular2 project.

I do however strongly agree that it's wrong to assume languages are similar and the meaning of inference obviously differs between all programming languages, often best to do tests to see what works, especially when your trying a new language, most programming languages are amazing once you get used to them.

But I don't feel that the question should not be down voted because of it's tone it's point was correct Typescript could do better in terms of inference, and the question was checking that his assumption was really correct as regressions in build versions or improvements in new versions 
are always possible and ongoing with all active languages.

Answer (score -1):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

Types in TypeScript are inferred when a variable is declared, not afterward. What you're doing wrong is expecting them to be inferred after the fact.

> How to make TS really infer types?

Do this:

```
var a = 33; 
a=true; // error
```

Comment: So how does Haxe do it if "what I'm doing is wrong"? Of course I know about this simplest way to infer on init, thanks for double explanation.

Comment: @shal Haxe is a different programming language that apparently allows inferring the types after the fact. What you're doing is wrong _in TypeScript_. TypeScript and Haxe are different languages and your expectation for them to act the same is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Alright, I just asked if I am doing anything wrong and if it's possible to do the same in TS. No need to be so spiteful and downvote my question only because of my curiosity. Maybe it's important that I've noticed this difference nobody else did, so it's useful for other Haxe developers, huh?

Comment: @shal Your question was downvoted for its low quality. The way you've worded it, it comes across as though you're just complaining that TypeScript can't do something that another language can do. If you dropped the negativity and plainly asked "Is there a way to do something like this in TypeScript?" I think your question would get a much better reception.